# Keep spaces in Pandas loaded from CSV

Tags: python, pandas

For example, my CSV file looks like:

```
Alex,Smith  , , 91
John,White  , , 15
```

How can I keep spaces after transformation to Pandas dataframe?

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype="string")
```

I'd like to verify that the first column has length of 4, the 2nd - 7, the 3rd - 1, the 4th - 3?

Comment: Your code works to do what you want, `'string'`, `'str'`, `'object'` wont modify the data. You can check with `df.agg(lambda x: x.str.len())` and you'll see you get 4,7,1,3 for the values in each column.

Comment: It might help to provide a list of column names to the `names` parameter, so the first row doesn’t get interpreted as column names.  Otherwise, as @ALollz mentions, there’s no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], header=None, dtype={'col4': object})

for col in df.columns:
    print(f"Length of {col}- {len(df.loc[0, col])}")
```